# ambiguous matches in iphone developer between System.keychain and login.keychain

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm running into a code signing problem. The solutions posted in SO and elsewhere to remove a duplicate certificate but I have already done that and the build error keeps popping. I'm out of ideas on what to do.

Under keychain access, there is login and System and both have iPhone developer: myName in it. Am I suppose to delete one of them? Which one should I delete? The login one or the System one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Most answers will tell you that you have a duplicate certificate. This is true for my case but the answers left out how to do it.

For me, my account expired and I have to get a new certificate and install it. Next, I looked at Keychain and removes the expired certificate but still got the error. What works for me is actually searching for "iPhone" in Keychain and removing all expired certificates. Apparently, some of it are not shown in System/Certificates or login/Certificates.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked for me. I could not find the duplicate until I did the search as you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for me - THANK YOU for posting this answer - been banging my head against the Apple for the last hour!

Comment: Wow this so weird that it's working (: I don't understand why these won't show up unless I explicitly search for them

Comment: Your answer really saved me! "Apparently, some of it are not shown in System/Certificates or login/Certificates."

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes a duplicate certificate f.e. in System is not shown in the Keychain Access. Just do the following: Go to View -> Show expired (or the like) and the duplicate should be shown. Did it for me :)

Answer (score 3):

For my case, I encountered while building for injectionforxcode.

Took a look at the Run Script, and it has `/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign "iPhone Developer"`. Since I have multiple accounts, the "iPhone Developer" has be changed to the specific one eg. "iPhone Developer: samwize"

I suppose any script running `codesign` could run into the same situation and would require this tweak.

Comment: I am facing same issue. I am trying to re-code sign for nested framework with "Automatically manage sign" option. Did you solve this issue ?